# JMeter can not destroy session

Tags: jmeter

I want to destroy my session with jmeter. I am using following code from my logout sampler as post beanshell processor:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
CookieManager cManager = sampler.getCookieManager();
for (int i=0;i<cManager.getCookieCount();i++){
    sampler.getCookieManager().remove(i);   
}
```

But the cookies are not destroyed.
What am I doing wrong?

Best regards, 
Peter

Comment: Hi Peter, did you check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12707635/how-to-clear-jsessionid-of-each-threaduser-in-jmeter-on-demand

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for not using "Clear cookies each iteration" box?

I'm also not too sure that it's the right way to delete cookies, I would go for [clear()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/CookieManager.html#clear()) method,  something like:

```
CookieManager cManager = sampler.getCookieManager();
cManager.clear();
sampler.setCookieManager(cManager);
```

Also cookie manager scope matters, depending on what you're trying to achieve it may worth moving the HTTP Cookie Manager to the root test plan level or vice versa, let each HTTP Request sampler have its own cookie manager as its child. See [Using the HTTP Cookie Manager](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) guide for more details.